# Why is my D3 SVG not getting the correct width/height from Angular element

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FL6N8nKlgJn3TxOA8A1G?p=preview) where I am trying to make my SVG 100% of the width and height of the screen.

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
  var firstElement = element[0];

  function updateSize() {
    $scope.height = firstElement.clientHeight;
    $scope.width = firstElement.clientWidth;
    $scope.svg.attr("height", $scope.height)
      .attr("width", $scope.width);
    $scope.render();
  }
  window.onresize = function(event){
    updateSize();
  }
  var report = d3.select(firstElement);
  $scope.svg = report.append("svg");
  updateSize();
}
```

It always seems off (either positive or negative) by 17px. Can someone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the resize more easily by setting the svg's dimensions to "100%".

This way you don't need to listen to window resize, the svg is scaled automatically.

```
  $scope.svg = report.append("svg");
  $scope.svg.attr("height", '100%')
    .attr("width", '100%')
```

[demo on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CJPsUrp6zXeYHe5jA4SY?p=preview).

Then you can add a [`viewBox` attribute](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html) to your svg if you want to scale the content of the svg in some way. I suggest reading [this guide](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/), quite smart about responsive SVG with d3.

P.S. I didn't verify, but your offset problem was maybe caused by the window resize event listener. "debouncing" it may then have fixed the issue.

Comment: I will look into this and vote up later (weird work proxy issues). But I hesitate to use 100% and I would prefer to know what is causing the discrepancy. I will also read through the viewBox article and respond ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: BTW in my view yours has scroll bars too (meaning it isn't 100% working)